# How can i solve '[TestNG] No tests found. Nothing was run'

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, testng, testng-eclipse

I am trying to run selenium with TestNG using Eclipse IDE. my code is given below.

```
package testNGtest;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class loginlogout {

public WebDriver driver;
String driverPath = "D:\\chromedriver.exe";
public String BaseURL = "https://xxxx.com/login";

@Test
public void loginPage() {               
    
    System.out.println(BaseURL);
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", driverPath);
    driver= new ChromeDriver();     
    driver.get(BaseURL);
    String currentUrl=driver.getCurrentUrl();
    Assert.assertTrue(currentUrl.contains("/login"));
 }

}
```

when i am running this test as testNG Test, it shows [TestNG] No tests found. Nothing was run. But when i am just run only with

```
System.out.println(BaseURL);
```

it displaying the BaseURL, but when adding the rest of the code, shows no tests found. I am using chrome browser version 91.0.4472.124 and chrome driver version i have downloaded from https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=91.0.4472.101/ and saved it to my D drive. And i have added two jar files 'client-combined-3.141.59.jar and client-combined-3.141.59-sources.jar' as Referenced libraries in my Project. As a test result, i can see the following

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 7.4.0

===============================================
Default test
Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 0, Passes: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================

[TestNG] No tests found. Nothing was run
Usage: <main class> [options] The XML suite files to run
Options:
-alwaysrunlisteners
  Should MethodInvocation Listeners be run even for skipped methods
  Default: true
-configfailurepolicy
  Configuration failure policy (skip or continue)
-d
  Output directory
-dataproviderthreadcount
  Number of threads to use when running data providers
-dependencyinjectorfactory
  The dependency injector factory implementation that TestNG should use.
-excludegroups
  Comma-separated list of group names to  exclude
-failwheneverythingskipped
  Should TestNG fail execution if all tests were skipped and nothing was 
  run. 
  Default: false
-groups
  Comma-separated list of group names to be run
-junit
  JUnit mode
  Default: false
-listener
  List of .class files or list of class names implementing ITestListener 
  or ISuiteListener
-methods
  Comma separated of test methods
  Default: []
-methodselectors
  List of .class files or list of class names implementing IMethodSelector
-mixed
  Mixed mode - autodetect the type of current test and run it with 
  appropriate runner
  Default: false
-objectfactory
  List of .class files or list of class names implementing 
  ITestRunnerFactory 
-overrideincludedmethods
  Comma separated fully qualified class names of listeners that should be 
  skipped from being wired in via Service Loaders.
  Default: false
-parallel
  Parallel mode (methods, tests or classes)
  Possible Values: [tests, methods, classes, instances, none]
-port
  The port
-reporter
  Extended configuration for custom report listener
-spilistenerstoskip
  Comma separated fully qualified class names of listeners that should be 
  skipped from being wired in via Service Loaders.
  Default: <empty string>
-suitename
  Default name of test suite, if not specified in suite definition file or 
  source code
-suitethreadpoolsize
  Size of the thread pool to use to run suites
  Default: 1
-testclass
  The list of test classes
-testjar
  A jar file containing the tests
-testname
  Default name of test, if not specified in suitedefinition file or source 
  code 
-testnames
  The list of test names to run
-testrunfactory, -testRunFactory
  The factory used to create tests
-threadcount
  Number of threads to use when running tests in parallel
-threadpoolfactoryclass
  The threadpool executor factory implementation that TestNG should use.
-usedefaultlisteners
  Whether to use the default listeners
  Default: true
-log, -verbose
  Level of verbosity
-xmlpathinjar
  The full path to the xml file inside the jar file (only valid if 
  -testjar was specified)
  Default: testng.xml
```

I am not understanding what is wrong here. Can anyone help me?

Comment: are you getting any exceptions?

Comment: Gautham, I have added what i can see in the console.

Comment: sorry, i missed some top portion of the console, now i added it. Actually i am not using any external xml file. It using the default one.

Comment: Can you try with putting `@Test` at the class level

Comment: showing the same result even when putting the @Test at the class level

Answer (score 1):

When i changed JavaSE-16 to JavaSE-1.8 in JRE section while creating the Java project, it ran successfully without modify anything in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Call the parent class method of launching browser in the child class.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in our project today.
The testclass itself looked good, but no tests were found.

So we debugged in the testng test execution and saw that a
NoClassDefFoundError exception was thrown in the "isTestNGClass"
method when the available methods are determined via the
getAvailableMethods methods in the ClassHelper class.

When the exception is thrown, this results in the "isTestNGClass"
method returning false which leads to the class not being a testng
class so that no tests are found.

The reason why the exception is thrown was that the base class
of the base class of the test class was moved to another package
and this package was not included in the dependencies of the pom.

Therefore this one class could not be found and hence the
NoClassDefFoundError and hence the class not being a testng
class which results in 0 tests to process.